# use of angular.forEach instead of for

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularjs, Please anyone tell how to use angular.forEach for below code

```
for(i=0;i<$scope.data.tabs.length;i++){ 
   $scope.data.tabs[i]['Position']=i+1;
}
```

Comment: Note that there's absolutely nothing wrong with using a `for` loop. For a simple array, it's much less complex than running it through [all this mess](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/Angular.js#L252)

Comment: Just fyi, native for loop is way better performance wise: https://jsperf.com/angular-foreach-vs-native-for-loop/29

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just have to remember that...

> The `iterator` function is invoked with `iterator(value, key, obj)`

See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach

```
angular.forEach($scope.data.tabs, function(tab, i) {
    tab.Position = i + 1;
});
```

So here, `tab` is the value of `$scope.data.tabs[i]` and `i` is the index of each tab in the array.

Comment: how i get index position of each tab ?

Comment: @Sachin not sure what you mean. The index of each `tab` in `$scope.data.tabs` is `i`.

Comment: i got index, i got confused between key, value so i asked about index, in our case i is index i got that

Comment: What is the reason to use the Angular iterator? Is it because it will call `$apply` when the `$scope` changes for data binding?

Comment: @geckob no, it doesn't do that. It's just a convenience function; sometimes you'll want to iterate the properties of an object, sometimes you'll want to keep any variables created within each iteration privately scoped